# JSR 352 : How do you write to a MVS Dataset from a Java Batch program?

Tags: file-io, jsr352, java-batch, mvs

I need to write to a non-VSAM dataset in the mainframe. I know that we need to use the ZFile library to do it and I found how to do it [here](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/tools/java/products/jzos/sdk700_jzos_samples.html)

I am running my Java batch job in the WebSphere Liberty on zOS. How do I specify the dataset? Can I directly give the DataSet a name like this?

`dsnFile = new ZFile("X.Y.Z", "wb,type=record,noseek");`

I am able to write it to a text file on the server itself using Java's File Writers but I don't know how to access a mvs dataset.

I am relatively new to the world of zOS and mainframe.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might be asking more generally how to use the **ZFile** API on WebSphere Liberty on z/OS.

Have you tried something like:

```
    String pdsName = ZFile.getSlashSlashQuotedDSN("X.Y.Z");
    ZFile zfile = new ZFile(pdsName , ...options...)
```

As far as batch-specific use cases, you might obviously have to differentiate between writing to a new file that's created for the first time on an original execution, as opposed to appending to an already-existing one on a restart.

You also might find some useful snipopets in this [doctorbatch.io repo](https://github.com/zblservices/doctorbatch.io), along with the original link you posted.

For reference, I'll copy/paste from the [ZFile Javadoc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.zsecurity.api.70.doc/com.ibm.jzos/com/ibm/jzos/ZFile.html):

```
ZFile dd = new ZFile("//DD:MYDD", "r");

Opens the DD namee MYDD for reading

ZFile dsn = new ZFile("//'SYS1.HELP(ACCOUNT)'", "rt");

Opens the member ACCOUNT from the PDS SYS1.HELP for reading text records

ZFile dsn = new ZFile("//SEQ", "wb,type=record,recfm=fb,lrecl=80,noseek");

Opens the data set {MVS_USER}.SEQ for sequential binary writing. Note that ",noseek" should be specified with "type=record" if access is sequential, since performance is greatly improved.
```

One final note, another couple useful **ZFile** helper methods are: **bpxwdyn()** and **getFullyQualifiedDSN()**.